# How to apply ICS style in my android app

Tags: android

i am develop android app with min sdk version android 2.2 and i am apply style for ics theme how can i do it apply all controls to ics style will work on 2.2 and above versions.i have no idea for apply theme for app.can help me guided for apply ics theme for my app how to do it with greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the holo everywhere library: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/

Comment: i am run the project getting error  No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/
 ProgressBarHolo.Large').!

Comment: Did you follow the readme? such as add: android:theme=“@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark” in your application manifest,

Answer (score 0):

use

1- Android Compatibility for fragment and [action bar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)..[Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Comment: i want to apply style for buttons and other controls in ics theme work for all android version same style!